# PHP OAuth getAccessToken method return value is insane

Tags: php, oauth

**I can easily work around this** however I wanted to ping the community to see if anyone knows *why* I'm seeing what I am.  I'm using the `OAuth` class to retrieve an access token, no problem there.  The weird part is the return value of the `getAccessToken` method.  For the return type [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.getaccesstoken.php) indicate:

> Returns an array containing the parsed OAuth response on success or FALSE on failure.

Ok, great.  Now let's see what the response actually looks like on success:

```
$response = $oauth->getAccessToken($authURL);
print_r($response);

// output:
Array
(
    [{"ok":true,"access_token":"xxxxxxxxx",...}] => 
)
```

That looks awfully strange to me. A one item array where the response is the **key** and the value is null?  I've never seen anything like this before, anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Just accept it. It is PHP. You remember "00-00-00 means 2000-00-00, which is 1999-12-00, which is 1999-11-30. No bug, perfectly normal": https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45647#1217272675 ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Yeah I know that one. But I'm not comfortable just accepting it, especially if it means my app will break as a result when I e.g. upgrade my php version. I'm hoping someone has something useful (like a bug report) they could point me to since I've come up empty handed.

Comment: Fear not, it is not a php itself, just a library. In any case upgrades should not be blindly applied but tested for regression first. Normally changes that brake backward compatibility are considered as major, but I wouldn't rely on it and test everything after any upgrade. Neither I would rely on someone has something. You can submit a bug yourself. Pull request that fixes the bug would be even better.